# Who are these three Justice League members during the fight with plant monsters?

Tags: character, young-justice

In *Young Justice* S01E14 aka *Revelation*, there are many Justice League members who fight with plant monsters but I am not able to identify three of them:

- First a blue guy with trident like shaft:

[image]

- Second a flying girl with purple aura:

[image]

- Third a dark complexion guy with superhuman strength and capable of flaying:

[image][image]

The rest were quite popular ones who were identifiable quite easily.

Who are these three?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. [Blue Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Devil)

[image]

2. [Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_(comics))

[image]

3. [Icon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icon_(comics))

[image]

Rocket is Icon's sidekick/protégé, and she later joins the Young Justice team full time. Icon is shown and has speaking roles a few times. Blue Devil didn't have any use throughout the first two seasons.